# Accessing raw SpO2, EDA, ECG, and temperature data

Tags: sensors, tizen

I am a researcher working on measuring physiological data such as SpO2, EDA, ECG, and temperature data. We would like to use Galaxy smartwatch 3 as a monitoring device for the research. However, before buying a lot of devices, i need clear and detailed information about the accessibility of SpO2, EDA, ECG, and temperature raw data. If i need to develop a samsung watch app that read and process through custom algorithms raw data coming from these sensors, is it possible?

I just want clear and detailed information before buying a lot of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out that I can use Tizen studio to create a native/web app to retrieve the data.